# How to track the Share button clicked on the ActionBar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I have added Share option to my ActionBarSherlock, this way:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {

menu.add("Share")
    .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_title_share_default)
    .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);
}
```

and on clicking this Icon i want to do something. how can i track the click on this ShareIcon??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create an XML file to define menu items.
For example `mymenu.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/share"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_title_share_default"
          android:title="@string/share"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
</menu>
```

Then in the `onCreateOptionsMenu` you will do:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.mymenu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

To handle the item selection:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.share:
            //do something for share
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

You can see more information in here:

> http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html
>
> http://actionbarsherlock.com/usage.html