# Add button to actionbar in android activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-actionbar

I would like to add a share button in an action bar of my current activity.

I don't know how to do it.

Is it possible to do this in activity ?

Here is the code of my activity :

```
package com.rss.utils;

import com.rss.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class WebBrowserViewActivity extends Activity {

    WebView webview;
    ProgressBar progressB = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.web_browser_view);

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        String url = intent.getStringExtra("URL");

        Log.d("WebBrowserViewActivity", "URL to load : " +url);

        progressB = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webViewArticle);    
        webview.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);

        // webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                if(progress < 100 && progressB.getVisibility() == ProgressBar.GONE){
                    progressB.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
                }
                progressB.setProgress(progress);
                if(progress == 100) {
                    progressB.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
                }
            }
        });

        webview.loadUrl(url);   
    }


}
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

++

Answer (score 1):

I've never done that before but I did some research for you and I'm pretty sure [this is what you're looking for.](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/shareaction.html)

This article will tell you what to do :)

Comment: Interesting Matthew, i will try this. Thanks

Comment: No problem, I'd tell you exactly how to do it but since I've never done it before either, giving you a useful link is best I can do

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @Matthew said, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12110676/1306419) answer on question [How to track the Share button clicked on the ActionBar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12110366/how-to-track-the-share-button-clicked-on-the-actionbar) provides step wise details to do the same. Some of other links that may help are: [How to activate "Share" button in android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17167701/how-to-add-share-button-to-android-app) and [Adding share action in ActionBar](http://baroqueworksdev.blogspot.ca/2012/01/adding-share-action-in-actionbar.html). Hope this helps.